# Tile editor with increasing number of features

Tags: lua

I've made a very simple tile editor.  I'd like for someone to review my code and tell me what I could improve on.  For example I'm bad at input management and creating systems that work nicely.  Say I want to add a way to pick what file it saves to by typing in the file path after a keypress.  How do I stop my program from doing other stuff currently associated with those key presses.  Right now my code just seems like a mess and the more features I add the more messy it becomes.
https://github.com/MonkeyToiletLadder/tile/tree/master/game

```
require "player"
require "map"
require "view"

windowWidth, windowHeight, flags = love.window.getMode()

windowWidthHalf = windowWidth / 2
windowHeightHalf = windowHeight / 2

atlas = love.graphics.newImage("dungeon_sheet.png")
quad = love.graphics.newQuad(0,0,16,16,atlas:getDimensions())



map = Map(atlas,16,16,20,20)
player = Player(0,0,100,0)
camera = Camera(0,0,player)
view = View(atlas,0,0,200,200)

updatable = {}
table.insert(updatable,player)
table.insert(updatable,camera)
table.insert(updatable,view)

drawable = {}
-- table.insert(drawable,player
table.insert(drawable,map)

currentTile = 54

function love.update(dt)
    if love.keyboard.isDown("s") then
        map:save("save.txt")
    end
    if love.keyboard.isDown("l") then
        map:load("save.txt")
    end 
    if love.keyboard.isDown("k") then
        atlas = love.graphics.newImage("dungeon_sheet.png")
        view.image = atlas
    end
    if love.keyboard.isDown("c") then
        map:clear()
    end
    -- Place tile
    if love.mouse.isDown(1) then
        mx,my = love.mouse.getPosition()
        wx = math.floor((camera.x + mx - windowWidthHalf) / map.tw) + 1
        wy = math.floor((camera.y + my - windowHeightHalf) / map.th) + 1
        if wx >= 1 and wx < map.width + 1 and wy >= 1 and wy < map.height  + 1 then
            map:add(wx,wy,currentTile)
        end
    -- Remove tile
    elseif love.mouse.isDown(2) then
        mx,my = love.mouse.getPosition()
        wx = math.floor((camera.x + mx - windowWidthHalf) / map.tw) + 1
        wy = math.floor((camera.y + my - windowHeightHalf) / map.th) + 1
        if wx >= 1 and wx < map.width + 1 and wy >= 1 and wy < map.height + 1 then
            map:remove(wx,wy,currentTile)
        end
    end

    -- Pick tile
    if view.selected then
        if love.mouse.isDown(1) then
            mx, my = love.mouse.getPosition()
            if mx > view.x and mx < view.x + view.image:getWidth() and my > view.y and my < view.y + view.image:getHeight() then
                tx = math.floor((mx + view.grip.x) / map.tw)
                ty = math.floor((my + view.grip.y) / map.th)
                id = tx + ty * map.sw
                currentTile = id
            end
        end
    end
    for _,v in ipairs(updatable) do
        v:update(dt)
    end
end

function love.draw()
    -- Canvas Draws
    love.graphics.push()
    love.graphics.translate(windowWidthHalf,windowHeightHalf)
    for _,v in ipairs(drawable) do
        v:draw(camera)
    end
    love.graphics.pop()

    view:draw()

    -- Tile selection
    local x = currentTile % map.sw * map.tw - view.grip.x
    local y = math.floor(currentTile / map.sw) * map.th - view.grip.y
    if x < view.x + view.width and y < view.y + view.height then
        love.graphics.rectangle("line",x,y,map.tw,map.th)
    end
end

function love.wheelmoved(x,y)
    currentTile = currentTile + y
    if currentTile < 0 then currentTile = 0 end
    if currentTile > map.sw * map.sh - 1 then currentTile = map.sw * map.sh - 1 end 
end
```

Map

```
class = require "clasp"

Map = class {
    init = function(self,atlas,tw,th,mw,mh)
        self.atlas = atlas
        self.data = {}
        self.width = mw
        self.height = mh
        self.size = self.width * self.height
        self.tw = tw
        self.th = th
        local sw,sh = self.atlas:getDimensions()
        self.sw = sw / self.tw
        self.sh = sh / self.th
        for i=1,self.height do
            self.data[i] = {}
            for j=1,self.width do
                self.data[i][j] = -1
            end
        end
        self.quad = love.graphics.newQuad(0,0,self.tw,self.th,self.sw,self.sh)
    end,
    draw = function(self,camera)
        love.graphics.rectangle("line",0-camera.x,0-camera.y,self.width*self.tw,self.height*self.th)
        for i=1,#self.data do
            for j=1,#self.data[i] do
                local id = self.data[i][j]
                if id ~= -1 then
                    local x = id % self.sw * self.tw
                    local y = math.floor(id/self.sw) * self.th
                    self.quad:setViewport(x,y,self.tw,self.th,self.atlas:getDimensions())
                    love.graphics.draw(atlas,self.quad,math.floor((j-1)*self.tw - camera.x),math.floor((i-1)*self.th - camera.y))
                end
            end 
        end 
    end,
    add = function(self,x,y,id)
        self.data[y][x] = id
    end,
    remove = function(self,x,y)
        self.data[y][x] = -1
    end,
    save = function(self,path)
        local file = assert(io.open(path,"w"))
        io.output(file)
        io.write("return {")
        for i=1,#self.data do
            io.write("{")
            for j=1,#self.data[i] do
                local id = self.data[i][j]
                    io.write(id..",")
            end
            io.write("},")
        end 
    io.write("}")
    io.close(file)
    end,
    load = function(self,path)
        if file_exists(path) then
            self.data = dofile(path)
        end 
    end,
    clear = function(self)
        for i=1,self.height do
            self.data[i] = {}
            for j=1,self.width do
                self.data[i][j] = -1
            end
        end
    end
}
```

view

```
class = require "clasp"
require "scrollbar"
require "utils"

View = class {
    init = function(self,image,x,y,width,height)
        self.image = image
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.quad = love.graphics.newQuad(0,0,self.width,self.height,self.image:getDimensions())
        self.selected = false
        self.grip = {}
        self.grip.x = 0
        self.grip.y = 0
        -- self.scrollbar = Scrollbar()
    end,
    draw = function(self)
        self.quad:setViewport(self.grip.x,self.grip.y,self.width,self.height,self.image:getDimensions())
        love.graphics.draw(self.image,self.quad,self.x,self.y)
        love.graphics.rectangle("line",self.x,self.y,self.width,self.height)
    end,
    update = function(self,dt)
        if love.mouse.isDown(1) then
            mx, my = love.mouse:getPosition()
            if isPointInRect(mx,my,self.x,self.y,self.width,self.height) then
                self.selected = true
            else
                self.selected = false
            end
        end
        if self.selected then
            if love.keyboard.isDown("up") then
                self.grip.y = self.grip.y - 64 * dt
            elseif love.keyboard.isDown("left") then
                self.grip.x = self.grip.x - 64 * dt
            elseif love.keyboard.isDown("down") then
                self.grip.y = self.grip.y + 64 * dt
            elseif love.keyboard.isDown("right") then
                self.grip.x = self.grip.x + 64 * dt
            end
            if self.grip.x < 0 then self.grip.x = 0 end
            if self.grip.x + self.width > self.image:getWidth() then
                if self.image:getWidth() - self.width < 0 then 
                    self.grip.x = 0 
                else 
                    self.grip.x = self.image:getWidth() - self.width 
                end 
            end
            if self.grip.y < 0 then self.grip.y = 0 end
            if self.grip.y + self.height > self.image:getHeight() then 
                if self.image:getHeight() - self.height < 0 then 
                    self.grip.y = 0 
                else 
                    self.grip.y = self.image:getHeight() - self.height 
                end 
            end
        end
    end
}
```

Comment: Maybe you missed the text on the right side when asking: "_Your question must contain code that is already working correctly, and **the relevant code sections must be embedded in the question**._" Questions must [include the code to be reviewed](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3653/120114). Links to code hosted on third-party sites are permissible, but the most relevant excerpts must be embedded in the question itself.

Comment: (Looks like a plan was needed: 1) pin down what to achieve 2) how to test you succeeded 3) code the tests 4) start the code with just the comments and heads of what to achieve 5) run the tests 6) code until the tests pass 7) resist featurism)